# How to simplify Lagrangian with partial derivatives and Einstein summation convention?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism

[image]

I have difficulties in simplifying the Lagrangian when there are partial derivatives.

The Lagrangian is 
$L = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu v}^2 - A_\mu J_\mu$

I have derived that

$L = -\frac{1}{4} (\partial_\mu A_v - \partial_v A_\mu)^2 - A_\mu J_\mu = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu A_v)^2 + 1/2 (\partial_\mu A_v)(\partial_v A_\mu) - A_\mu J_\mu$

But I can't see why
$(\partial_\mu A_v)(\partial_v A_\mu) = (\partial_\mu A_\mu)^2$

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model - Schwartz M.D.  page 37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add a total derivative to the Lagrangian without changing the resulting equations of motion. Note that $$\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\nu A^\mu+\partial_\nu(A^\nu\partial_\mu A^\mu)-\partial_\mu (A^\nu\partial_\nu A^\mu)=\partial_\nu A^\nu\partial_\mu A^\mu.$$